# Bug in form display when upgrading .NET version and editing form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, windows-forms-designer

First of all, I upgraded my project form .NET 3.5 to 4.0 recently. I had no problems.

But now I have made some changes and consequence is that form is displayed bad on all computers that have not installed Visual studio 2010. They have .NET 4.0, otherwise I could not run that program.

I only have to add one button and designer changes two other things:

```
 <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```

goes to (in .resx file)

```
<value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```

And pairs like:

```
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer3)).BeginInit();
    ...
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.splitContainer3)).EndInit();
```

appear in .Designer.cs InitializeComponent()

If i revert this changes in code form is displayed OK on all computers, if I leave them form is missing many child controls and it seams like most of them slipped out of screen, but only on computers which don't have VS2010. How to fix this and how is this connected with having VS2010 installed on computer?

Comment: What do you mean by "displayed bad": an error or something else?

Comment: @Richard Many controls are not visible, like they are out of visible area. Something is bad in layout, something like window size is different than form size and then all controls which are close to bottom  and right side of form are missing.

Comment: Has the form changed size? If so, it might be anchoring

Comment: Are those controls visible in the debugger (or to diagnostics code: iterating through the form's child controls)?

Comment: @Bridge No. Almost like form surface size is Window size * 1.5. But I don't see connection between cause and symptoms.

Comment: @Richard  Yes, in debugger is OK, like on all other computers which have VS2010 installed, so I can't debug there because everything is OK. Where problems exist I can't debug because there is no VS2010 installed. Funny problem. Also I can confirm that controls exist, because I can select buttons with tab and push them with enter. Only layout looks bad.

Comment: Perhaps time for working and not working screenshots?

Comment: Could it be that the DPI on your dev PC is different than on the other PCs?

Comment: @AVIDeveloper Yes, that is cause of problems. All dev PCs I tried had elevated DPI, all others didn't. I knew that having VS2010 installed is too strange to be a cause, but that was my only connection. When I set default DPI on one of dev PCs than same problem occured. If you make answer from this I will accept it and vote up also. Thx.

Comment: @Richard Thx, I didn't know for screenshots on stackoverflow. I guess i will look into DPI connection first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a DPI issue where the DPI on your dev. PC (e.g. 120dpi) is different than the DPI on your other PCs (e.g. 96dpi).

If you don't intent to support different DPIs in your application, then just make sure that you develop your code on a PC which is set to the target DPI resolution (usually 96dpi).

If you would like to support various DPI resolutions, then `Form.AutoScaleMode` would be a good start. StackOverflow is also filled with resources about DPI problems and solutions.

Good luck.

Comment: Thx. It is very interesting that everything is OK when in .resx file I have Version=2.0.0.0. Things get messy only when I edit form and designer changes Version to 4.0.0.0 and adds few other lines. I will stick to Version 2.0.0.0 for now.